# JAVA I don't understand Try-catch

Tags: java, try-catch

This is my first time here. I'm starting to learn how to code, so I honestly hope this question I have is not something I can find over here! (I promise I searched for a while, but since I'm a noob in this topic, I didn't found anything understandable for me in order to resolve my doubt).

I'm doing a simple game in JAVA, in which the program generates a random number and the player has to guess the number generated.
When the player enters a number, the game displays a hint, saying if it is higher or lower than the number generated randomly.

The program itself works fine if you enter just numbers, but I want to add a try-catch statement to handle bad user input.

I tried using the statement as I show in my code, but I can't understand why it's not working properly, because when I enter something different of a number, the exception is catched and it prints on console the System.out.println(), but program terminates when this happens.

I would like to try-catch just to get the exception of entering not a number without terminating the program every time the exception is catched.
How can I fix this?

Thanks a lot for your help!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HiLo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);  //Creates Scanner object to read from keyboard
        String playAgain = "";  //if == y, game restarts
        try {
            do {
                // Create a random number for the user to guess
                int theNumber = (int)(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
                //System.out.println(theNumber);        //Uncoment this in case we want to know the number (for testing).
                int guess = 0;  //Number entered by the player
                int count = 0;  //Number of tries of guessing the number
                while(guess != theNumber){
                    System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 100:");
                    guess = scan.nextInt(); //Reads the number typed on the keyboard by the player
                    count++;    //Plus 1 every time a number is entered
                    System.out.println("You entered " + guess +".");
                    if(guess < theNumber) { //If number entered is smaller
                        System.out.println("The number is bigger" + ", try again!");
                        System.out.println("Number of tries: " + count);
                    } else if(guess > theNumber) { //If number entered is bigger
                        System.out.println("The number is smaller" + ", try again!");
                        System.out.println("Number of tries: " + count);
                    } else {    //If both previous cases are false
                        System.out.println("Congratulations! You've found the number!");
                    }
                }
                //Once guess == theNumber
                System.out.println("Number of tries: " + count);
                System.out.println("Play again? (y/n)");
                playAgain = scan.next();    //Reads the String entered from keyboard by the player
            }
            while(playAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));     //If player enters y, start again.
            //Otherwise
            System.out.println("Thank you for playing! Goodbye :)");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Incorrect entering! Please enter a number between 1 and 100.");
        }
        scan.close();   //Close scanner
    }   //Close main
}   //Close class
```

Comment: The Program terminates because after your `catch` you're closing the scanner and return from main, so what did you expect?

Comment: Then how can I fix this? If I modify the structure of the do-while statement an error pops up in eclipse and don't allow me to compile.
I thought about adding "guess = scan.nextInt()" after the "System.out.println()", but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

place try-catch inside the while loop and reinstantiate the scanner object (scan = new Scanner(System.in) inside the catch block.

```
while (guess != theNumber) {
                    try {                       
                        System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 100:");
                        guess = scan.nextInt(); // Reads the number typed on the
                        // keyboard by the player
                        count++; // Plus 1 every time a number is entered
                        System.out.println("You entered " + guess + ".");
                        if (guess < theNumber) { // If number entered is smaller
                            System.out.println("The number is bigger" + ", try again!");
                            System.out.println("Number of tries: " + count);
                        } else if (guess > theNumber) { // If number entered is
                            // bigger
                            System.out.println("The number is smaller" + ", try again!");
                            System.out.println("Number of tries: " + count);
                        } else { // If both previous cases are false
                            System.out.println("Congratulations! You've found the number!");
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("Incorrect entering! Please enter a number between 1 and 100.");
                        scan = new Scanner(System.in);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Great! Works like charm! Thank you so much!
I still have one question: why you have to create another scanner object? I don't quite understand, can you explain it to me so I can learn?
Thanks for your time!!

Comment: One more comment, I needed one more scanner object to make it work perfectly, but I'm not sure why hahaha. If you could explain it would be awesome! :D Thanks!

Comment: scan.nextInt() will be executed first and then only it assigns input value to guess variable. Non int input will cause scan.nextInt() to throw an exception. While looping scan.nextInt() keeps throwing exception because it holds the non int input. This will cause infinite loop. To solve this we need to make sure scanner object isn't holding non int input value. One way to do this is by creating a new Scanner object in catch block.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Regards!

Answer (score -1):

You need to understand the working of the try-catch block. You don't need to surround the entire code within try. Just put that part of the code which causes an exception. So, in your case just surround `guess = scan.nextInt();` with try and then catch an exception. Because, here this statement raises an exception when the input is not an integer. This way you can ensure that the user input is valid for each iteration of the `while(guess != theNumber)` loop.

Edit_1:
I removed the `try-catch` blocks from your code and added the following & it works fine for me:

```
try{
  guess = scan.nextInt();} //Reads the number typed on the keyboard by the player
catch (InputMismatchException e){
  System.out.println("Incorrect entering! Please enter a number between 1 and 100.");
  scan.nextLine();
  continue;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought that could be the solution, but when I tried, program finished because the while condition is always false if you enter a word (for example) :/

Comment: You will need to add `scan.nextLine()` in the `catch` block to be able to use this. I have edited my answer to show what I mean.

Comment: Why do you use the continue statement there?

Comment: Because when `guess` is invalid, I don't want to proceed further into the loop, i.e. I don't want `count++` and statements after that to execute. Instead I want the next iteration of the loop to begin.